# Pattern Matching - String Search

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to work out a formula to match a following pattern:
input string example:

`'444'/'443'/'434'/'433'/'344'/'334'/'333'`

if any of the patterns above exist in a particular input string I want to match it as the same pattern.

also is it possible to do a variable substitution using regex? meaning check for the 3 chars of the string by using each character as a variable and just doing an increment/decrement for each character? so that you dont have to specify the particular number ranges (hardcoding the pattern string ) for different patterns?

Is there any good library one can use for this?? I was working with Pattern class in java.

If you have any link which would be helpful please pass it through :) 
Thank you.

Comment: ya that also. (3/4)(3/4)(3/4) for each character.
similarly wanted to do it for multiple numbers. so was looking for some kind of variable substitution ( for each character ) if that is possible in regex.

Comment: Personally, I have trouble understanding what exactly you want. Can you provide some examples? (unless _codaddict_ answered your question, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first consider this pattern: `[34]{3}`

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it matches exactly one of the characters in the set. The `{n}` is an exact finite [*repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

So, `[34]{3}` informally means "exactly 3 of either `'3'` or `'4'`". Thus, it matches `"333"`, `"334"`, `"343"`, `"344"`, `"433"`, `"434"`, `"443"`, `"444"`, and nothing else.

As a string literal, the pattern is `"[34]{3}"`. If you don't want to hardcode this pattern, then just generate similar-looking strings that follows this template `"[…]{n}"`. Just put the characters that you want to match in the `…`, and substitute `n` with the number you want.

Here's an example:

```
  String alpha = "aeiou";
  int n = 5;

  String pattern = String.format("[%s]{%s}", alpha, n);

  System.out.println(pattern);
  // [aeiou]{5}
```

We've now seen that the pattern is not hardcoded, but rather programmatically generated depending on the values of the variables `alpha` and `n`. The pattern `[aeiou]{5}` will 5 consecutive lowercase vowels, e.g. `"ooiae"`, `"ioauu"`, `"eeeee"`, etc.

It's again not clear if you just want to match these kinds of strings, or if they have to appear like `'…'/'…'/'…'/'…'/'…'`. If the latter is desired, then simply compose the pattern as desired, using repetition and [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) as necessary. You can also just programmatically copy and paste the pattern 5 times if that's simpler. Here's an example:

```
  String p5 = String.format("'%s'/'%<s'/'%<s'/'%<s'/'%<s'", pattern);

  System.out.println(p5);
  // '[aeiou]{5}'/'[aeiou]{5}'/'[aeiou]{5}'/'[aeiou]{5}'/'[aeiou]{5}'
```

This will now match strings like `"'aeooi'/'eeiuu'/'uaooo'/'eeeia'/'eieio'"`.

#### Caveat

Do be careful about what goes in `alpha`. Specifically, `-`, `[`. `]`, `&&`, `^`, etc, are special metacharacters in Java character class definition. If you restrict `alpha` to contain only digits/letters, then you will probably not run into any problems, but e.g. `[^a]` does *NOT* mean "either `'^'` or `'a'`". It in fact means "anything but `'a'`. See [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for exact character class syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
('\\d{3}'/){6}'\\d{3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern.Compile` takes a `String` as its parameter. Though that's probably most often supplied in the form of a string literal, if you have variable upper and lower bounds for your pattern, you can use something like `StringBuilder` to build your string, then pass that result to `Pattern.Compile`.